# WooCommerce (WordPress) - Last product in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

http://tp4x4.v2webdesign.co.uk/products/

I'm wondering if it possible to find out when the category/product loop is the last.

I'm in the process of building a custom template and to organise the products I am using the foundation grid system.

This is in files: content-product-cat.php & content-product.php

```
  <?php if ($woocommerce_loop['loop']&1){ ?>
    <div class="row product-grid-row"> <?php }?>
      <div class="product-category product large-6 small-12 columns">

    content stuff is here
      </div>

  <?php if ($woocommerce_loop['loop']&2) { ?></div><?php } ?>
```

This code opens the .product-grid-row  for each odd number and closes it for each even number, creating 2 products per row.

The problem is when the last product is an odd number or there is an odd number if products/categories.

If there is a way to determine the number of categories/products in that loop I can simply use that variable:

```
if ($lastinloop) echo "</div>";
```

I have also tried using the loop_shop_columns feature of WooCommerce but this poses the same problem if the last product is not at the end of a row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
global $wp_query;
echo "Total Records :".$wp_query->found_posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

better late than never :) I'm not sure about "correctness" but it works.

My /mytheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php contains

```
<div class="container">
```

So.. now change this line in /mytheme/woocommerce/content-product.php:

```
global $product, $woocommerce_loop;
```

to:

```
global $product, $woocommerce_loop, $wcp_last_loop;
```

and add this to end:

```
$wcp_last_loop = $woocommerce_loop; // save it globaly for use in /mytheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-end.php
```

And my /mytheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-end.php contains:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product Loop End
 */

global $wcp_last_loop;

if ( 1 == $wcp_last_loop['loop'] % $wcp_last_loop['columns'] ) {
    echo '</div><!-- .row -->'; // end of .row after odd product
}

?>

</div><!-- .container -->
```